# Ошибка в запросе post

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import requests
import bs4


url = 'https://url/api/Import? 
code=-some-base-64=='

HEADERS = {'Accept': '*/*',
           'Connection': 'keep-alive',
           'User-Agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.29.0',
           'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
       }

body = {

        "tenancyId":"GUID",
        "applicationId":"GUID"

     }

        req = requests.post(url, data=body, headers=HEADERS)
        print(req)
```

Это мой код. И так, этот запрос в постмане отрабатывает ответ получаю 200. В питоне ошибка, вот текст 500 - мол проблема на серваке, но с ним все ок ведь в постмане отработало. Помогите плиз разобраться 2 часа уже сижу не могу понять в чем дело. Хидеры вроде те же

Comment: Поставил тревогу для модератора на "войну правок" и вандализм вопроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы должны использовать аргумент `json`, а не `data`:

```
req = requests.post(url, json=body, headers=HEADERS)
```